# AJAX Doesnt pass the data to php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have this following jquery/ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').on('click', '.view_data', function() {
    $("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    var pdf_liste_no = $(this).attr("id");
    const imageURL = "../images/loadaq.gif";
    swal({
        title: '',
        text: 'Yükleniyor...',
        icon: imageURL,
        buttons: false,
        closeOnClickOutside: false
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "gosterduzenlesil.php",
        method: "post",
        data: {
            pdf_liste_no: pdf_liste_no
        },
        success: function(data) {
            swal.close()
            $('#kullanici').html(data);
            $('#dataModal').modal("show");
            $("button").removeAttr("disabled");
        },
        error: function(err) {
            swal({
                title: "Bilgi",
                text: "Devre Dışı!",
                icon: "error",
                button: "Tamam",
                closeOnClickOutside: false
            });
            $("button").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

});

the data from .html file passes thru the ajax and after ajax sumbits to data to another .php file 
i have this code in that php file

```
if(isset($_POST["pdf_liste_no"])){
}
```

this php code doesnt see the post so the problem is the data from ajax doesnt pass thru to another .php file i dont know why .php page doesnt see that data

and this is my directory tree
public_html
yonetim
gosterduzenlesil.php

Comment: Are you sure the id is placed as attribute on `<div class="view_data">` element? Please show your HTML.

Comment: right away 
`echo '<td><button class="btn btn-outline-primary view_data" id='.$row['pdf_liste_no'].' name="view"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></td>';`

Comment: Check if the pdf_liste_no variable is really sent to PHP file (you can do it in the inspect part of the browser, in the network tab, you can see the posted data).

Comment: Check the browser developer tools. In the network tab, what  do you see in the request headers?

Comment: i have fixed it and i shared it in the comment below

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem it was because of .htaccess file it was deleting .php so i just deleted the .php from ajax url and it worked